# how to get the possibility density of the sum of all components of a multidimensional variate?

Tags: statistics

I encountered a problem in a paper. It said that if $X=(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)$ has a Continuous Gaussian distribution, then the inner product with a $Z$ has a normal distribution. Is it true? If yes, what about the mean and variance?

Comment: Is $Z$ a given constant vector or a random variable?  Are the components of $X$ independent or is $X$ multivariate normal, or something else?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Z is a given constant. I don't know whether the components of X are independent. I am only sure that X is distributed as a continuous Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is jointly normally distributed.  Then, if $z=(z_1,...,z_n)$ is a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then indeed $Y=z \cdot X$ is a Gaussian random variable
with mean $\mu \cdot z$ where $\mu = (\mu_1,...,\mu_n)$ is the mean of $X$ and variance $$ z_1^2\sigma_1^2+...z_n^2\sigma_n^2 $$ where $\sigma_i^2$ is the variance of $x_i$.

The proof is just an extension [of the $n=2$ case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in the paper, it says that **X** is distributed as a continuous Gaussian. Probability density of **X** is computed as $e^{-\pi||X||}$. Thus, I think there is a difference between your explanation and the problem. Sorry, I did not describe the question clearly.

Comment: Let z $\in R^{n}$, **h** be distributed as the continuous Gaussian. The probability density is computed by $e^{-\pi ||h||}$. Then $<z ,h >$ is a normal variable. Is this correct?

Comment: Hmm, then I am misunderstanding the question.  Don't know what the paper means by "continuous Gaussian".  That density function looks like that of an exponential distribution.

Comment: OK. I will think about the problem later. Thank you for your kindly reply.